How to convert a x-d list to an array？
From other questions, I know how to convert a 1-d list to an array. The function "Store" inside can finish this. However, I would like to get a general method to do this job.
Here's an example to explain my question:
i, j = Ints('i j')
VG = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
A = Array('A',IntSort(),ArraySort(IntSort(), IntSort()))

I need to make the array A equal the list VG, because I will add some constraints like this:
s = Solver()
s.add(FORALL([i,j],Implies(And(i>=0, i<9, j>=0, j<3), A[i][j]>=0)))

If I use the list L to do this:
s.add(FORALL([i,j],Implies(And(i>=0, i<9, j>=0, j<3), VG[i][j]>=0)))
z3 reported below error messages:
s.add(ForAll([i,j],Implies(And(i>=0, i<9, j>=0, j<3), VG[i][j]>=0)))
                                                          ~~^^^
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not ArithRef

I searched for information about this error message on Stack Overflow, like this Error with quantifier in Z3Py, so I want to use this method to solve my question. But when the list have more dimensions, this method doesn't seems to work.
I don't know how many dimensions the list has, and I don't know the size of each dimension in the array. All I have is just a list, like the 'VG' above, I need to get a result for some constraints like 'VG[i][j]>0', so how to solve it? Any better methods?

Short answer: You can't use an SMTLib Array if you don't know the dimensions of your input array ahead of time. An SMTLib array has constant dimensions that are explicitly declared: They cover the entire range of the declared type; they do not "adjust" their dimensions based on the input you have.
But you're programming in z3py; so what you need to do is to dynamically declare your array based on the shape of your input list. This can be error prone in general as every expression you write will have to consider this variability; but that'd be the only way to handle such a problem using internal data-structures. (An alternative might be to declare your own-data type; but that can get rather hairy itself.)
As a proof-of-concept, the following would work under the assumptions:

Each element of the input has the exact same shape
There are no empty lists as elements in the input

from z3 import *

# Assumes:
#    1. each element of the input has the exact same shape
#    2. There are no empty lists
# Otherwise, you can't map it to SMTLib anyhow; unless you
# make some further assumptions.
def smtType (a):
    if type(a) != list:
        return IntSort()
    else:
        return ArraySort(IntSort(), smtType(a[0]))

Some tests:
print(smtType([0]))
print(smtType([[0]]))
print(smtType([[[0]]]))
print(smtType([[[[0]]]]))

This prints:
Array(Int, Int)
Array(Int, Array(Int, Int))
Array(Int, Array(Int, Array(Int, Int)))
Array(Int, Array(Int, Array(Int, Array(Int, Int))))

You can use this methodology to keep track of the "dimensions" and code accordingly. This won't be terribly easy unfortunately, but there's no other way to code this in the strongly-typed SMTLib theories.

Thanks! I need to learn more about this.
